# How to enable review section in magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, review

I have 'Write a review' link in my product details page.It was working fine in magento 1.9.0.1. Now when I migrated my code to fresh magento 1.9.2.2 The link is not working instead a page like this is opening indicating error:

[image]

Should I do anything at backend admin panel?

Here is my code which I used to display the 'Write a review' link in details page.

```
<div class="extra-info">
            <?php 
                        $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($_product->getId()); // returns 

                        $reviewsCount = $summaryData->getReviewsCount();
                        if($reviewsCount){

                            }
                        else{ ?> <div id="customer-reviews" class="box-collateral box-reviews">
            <p class="no-rating"><a href="<?php echo $this->getStoreUrl()."/review/product/list/id/".$_product->getId()."/#review-form";?>">Write a Review</a></p>
    </div><?php }
                        ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>

            </div>
```

Comment: Go to 'system > configuration > advanced' in admin and enable `Mage_Review`

Comment: It is already enabled

Comment: Can you tell me where this error coming? which url you accesing?

Comment: Kindly check the question edited.

Comment: Check if including "index.php" in URL resolves the issue. Generally, it happens when Web Server Rewrites in not enabled.

Comment: do you mean including like this `"index.php/review/product/list/id/"`

Comment: When I add index.php like mentioned in previous comment the error is like "There was no 404 CMS page configured or found."

Answer (score 1):

I just replaced the `getStoreUrl()` method in the above mentioned code  with `getUrl()` and it worked.